# How to use grep to capture match?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to write a script that increments an integer found in a config file. I'm trying to use `grep` to find the current value:

```
$ grep versionNumber myfile.conf
          versionNumber 123789
^ whitespace
          ^ the key I need to match
                        ^ the value I need to capture
```

My desired result is to capture the `123789` in the example above.

What do I need to do in order to capture this value?

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"? Do you mean "print" or something else? What's the desired output of the script you want to write given the input file you posted?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
grep versionNumber myfile.conf | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
```

or this

```
grep versionNumber myfile.conf | awk '{print $2}'
```

or this

```
grep versionNumber myfile.conf | cut -d' ' -f2
```

or if you have GNU grep with support for the `-P` mode:

```
grep -oP 'versionNumber \K\d+' myfile.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/versionNumber/{print $2}' myfile.conf
```

Comment: Good one, eliminates need to use `grep`

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -oP` (pcre mode);

```
s='          versionNumber 123789'
grep -oP 'versionNumber\h+\K\S+' <<< "$s"

123789
```

Answer (score 0):

*script that increments an integer found in a config file* using Gnu awk v. 4.1.0+:

A test file:

```
$ cat > file
foo
           versionNumber 123789
bar
```

Using inplace edit feature:

```
$ awk -i inplace '/versionNumber/ {n=index($0,"v"); sub($2,$2+1); printf "%-"n"s\n", $0; next} 1' file
```

The result:

```
$ cat file
foo
           versionNumber 123790
bar
```

Explanation:

Key to editing the file inplace is `-i inplace`

```
/versionNumber/ {          # if versionNumber found in record
    n=index($0,"v")        # count leading space amount to n
    sub($2,$2+1)           # increment the number in second field
    printf "%-"n"s\n", $0  # print n space before the (trimmed) record
    next                   # skip print in the next line
} 1                        # print all other records as were
```